# Using join prevents index use on where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Is there a way to use both an index for `join` and a separate index for a different `where` clause?
Whenever I add the `join` query- it causes the `where` index to be ignored.

I have Users table (80,000 records)

| id | company_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

with btree index on company_id:
`PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`
`Index btree on company_id`

Comments table (7,000,000 records)

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 |
| 33 | 3 |

with btree index on user_id:

- `PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)`
- `Index btree on user_id`

If I use a simple where - it uses the company index:

```sql
    SELECT users.id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134,
      16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145,
      16146, 16147, 16333)
    
> Index Scan using index_users_on_company_id on users  (cost=0.29..213.88 rows=97 width=4)
  Index Cond: (company_id = ANY ('{16111,16198,16113,16133,16135,16134,16136,16137,16138,16139,16141,16142,16143,16144,16145,16146,16147,16333}'::integer[]))
```

But when I add, although it uses user_id index at comments, it stopped using the company_id index (`Parallel Seq Scan` instead of previously used `Index Scan`):

```sql
SELECT users.id
FROM users INNER JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134, 16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145, 16146, 16147, 16333)

Gather  (cost=1000.43..9632.88 rows=1410 width=4)
  Workers Planned: 1
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.43..8491.88 rows=829 width=4)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..2742.06 rows=57 width=4)
              Filter: (company_id = ANY ('{16111,16198,16113,16133,16135,16134,16136,16137,16138,16139,16141,16142,16143,16144,16145,16146,16147,16333}'::integer[]))
        ->  Index Only Scan using index_comments_on_user_id on comments  (cost=0.43..98.21 rows=266 width=4)
              Index Cond: (user_id = users.id)
```

To summarize:

Is there a way to use both the company_id index and the user_id index in a single query?

Basically substitute the `Parallel Seq Scan on users` with `Index Scan using index_users_on_company_id on users` at the second query?

UPDATE:

After setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0, as @Anton Grig suggested, The same query, uses index instead of `Parallel Seq Scan`
It does performs faster. I wonder if there's a less intrusive way..

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..9998.67 rows=1410 width=4)
  ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_company_id on users  (cost=0.29..213.88 rows=97 width=4)
        Index Cond: (company_id = ANY ('{16111,16198,16113,16133,16135,16134,16136,16137,16138,16139,16141,16142,16143,16144,16145,16146,16147,16333}'::integer[]))
  ->  Index Only Scan using index_comments_on_user_id on comments  (cost=0.43..98.21 rows=266 width=4)
        Index Cond: (user_id = users.id)
```

UPDATE2:

I'll add the full query (uses `left outer join`) I'm running, not a minified version for question

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT comments.tag_id) FILTER (WHERE comments.archived = FALSE ) AS tags_count
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134, 16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145, 16146, 16147, 16333)
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my test example, the Index Cond was used in both cases. I would try to disable the parallel query by using SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0, this should prompt the engine to use the Index Cond instead and don't forget to restore the default value for the Set after.

Comment: @AntonGrig updated answer, Like you said it uses index when I'm setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0

Comment: if users->comments is 1->N (what I assume) the query makes no sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If using max_parallel_workers_per_gather seems intrusive, try changing the query while maintaining logic. I would try something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM comments 
WHERE user_id In (SELECT id
                  FROM users
                  WHERE company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134,
                                       16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145,
                                       16146, 16147, 16333))
```

In my case, it still uses `Index Cond` and is executed in about the same time.

I put it in the answer block to ease the perception of the query.

UPDATE:

If the selectivity of column user_id in table comments is low, I would suggest using `Exist` operator as follows:

```
Select id
From users
Where Exists (Select user_id From comments Where user_id=users.id) And
      company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134,
                     16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145,
                     16146, 16147, 16333)
```

Note: It also removes duplicates from the output.

UPDATE2:

I would create another index in table `User` instead of the previous one to provide `Index Scan only -> Index Cond`.

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON Users(company_id, id);
```

and I would change the query as follows:

```
Select id, 
       (Select COUNT(DISTINCT comments.tag_id)
        From comments
        Where comments.archived = FALSE And user_id=users.id) As tags_count
From users
Where company_id IN (16111, 16198, 16113, 16133, 16135, 16134,
                     16136, 16137, 16138, 16139, 16141, 16142, 16143, 16144, 16145,
                     16146, 16147, 16333)
```

Comment: Added full query, it uses left outer join, I'll try to apply what you wrote